# Increase polygonal resolution of ggplot polar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a large polar graph/pie chart of 40+ bars/rings with **ggplot2** (using **geom_bar** and **coord_polar(theta="y")** ), and am finding that the y axis plot compression causes the innermost rings to have very poor polygon resolution.

Anyone know of a way to bump up the polygonal resolution?

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = sort(sample(1:40, 400, replace=TRUE)), 
  y = sample(0:9, 400, replace=TRUE)
)


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position="fill") + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="pink")
```

[image]

This is what I mean by the geometric resolution I'm trying to achieve. I managed this by plotting just 5 levels.

[image]

When I increase to 40 levels the central polygons lose their smoothness and become too jagged, like this:

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote you if you stick in your code and some example data.

Comment: And I might even downvote if you don't post reproducible code and sample data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for tips on asking a great question.

Comment: Cheers! This code reproduces the problem. If you save to PDF and zoom into the centre you'll see what I mean. 

`df <- data.frame( x = sort(sample(1:40, 400, replace=TRUE)), `
 `y = sample(0:9, 400, replace=TRUE))`
`ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y)) + `
 `geom_bar(stat='identity', position="fill") + `
 `coord_polar(theta="y") + `
 `scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="pink")`

Comment: OK, so the real problem is not in your code, it is with getting more resolution in your pdf.  What is your code for saving to pdf?  You can adjust the resolution there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've just tried increasing PDF document size but with the same result.  Not sure how to increase PDF resolution, but anyway it outputs this kind of plot to vector so I don't see how it could make a difference.  I'm using `pdf(file="filname.pdf", width=12, height=12) [plot code]  dev.off()`

Comment: I don't think this is an image resolution issue. I think the innermost rings are simply being drawn with too few polygonal segments. It's possible this is a bug. You might have more luck asking about this on the ggplot2 mailing list.

Comment: This is because `coord_polar` determines the number of division by the physical length of the path. If the length of the circumference is short, the number of division is small. In most cases, this would be ok, but as you say there will be the case where you need the larger number of division.

Comment: Good advice thanks - I'll post back if I find a solution

Comment: This was what I wanted to achieve: http://geotheorydotorg.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/pi-circle.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is with the `ggplot2:::coord_munch` function, which has an argument `segment_length` with a default value of 0.01:

https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/coord-munch.r

I don't think there's any place to pass in arguments that will make it down to `coord_munch`'s `segment_length` argument. One way to deal with it for now is to replace `coord_munch` with a wrapper function that has a different default value for `segment_length`.

```
# Save the original version of coord_munch
coord_munch_old <- ggplot2:::coord_munch

# Make a wrapper function that has a different default for segment_length
coord_munch_new <- function(coord, data, range, segment_length = 1/500) {
  coord_munch_old(coord, data, range, segment_length)
}
# Make the new function run in the same environment
environment(coord_munch_new) <- environment(ggplot2:::coord_munch)

# Replace ggplot2:::coord_munch with coord_munch_new
assignInNamespace("coord_munch", coord_munch_new, ns="ggplot2")
```

Once that's done, you can run the example again:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = sort(sample(1:40, 400, replace=TRUE)), 
  y = sample(0:9, 400, replace=TRUE)
)

pdf('polar.pdf')
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position="fill") + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="pink")
dev.off()
```

Assigning values in a namespace is only supposed to be used for development purposes, so this is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: I believe this only works with version 0.9.0 or higher; version 0.8.9 does not have `coord_munch`

Comment: Works great, thanks so much. I had to add `is_closed=False` to the paramaters for `munch`'ing. Works great for more than a decade :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wch's correct diagnosis and workaround above, an alternative workaround is suggested by Jean-Olivier via the ggplot2 Google Group:

> Instead, changing the data to increase the coordinate values in the
>   data space, by doing something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x+100, y=y, fill=y)) +
 geom_bar(stat='identity', position="fill") +
 coord_polar(theta="y") +
 scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="pink")
```

Thanks everyone.